# How do I call the synthesize method of the TextToSpeech service within the java-sdk API?

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

The API documentation can be found here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk

When I try and use the service, it authenticates properly and then fails on the synthesize method.

```
 TextToSpeech tts_service = new TextToSpeech();
 tts_service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

 tts_service.synthesize("The cat sat on the mat", Voice.EN_LISA, "audio/ogg; codecs=opus");
```

The stack trace for the error is shown below. I have tried the synthesize method without the voice and format arguments too (since it has a default) but the service fails with the same error when I do this.

> Nov 25, 2015 4:58:55 PM
>   com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService execute SEVERE:
>   https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?text=The%20cat%20sat%20on%20the%20mat&voice=en-US_LisaVoice&Accept=audio%2Fogg%3B%20codecs%3Dopus,
>   status: 400, error: The argument(s) [u'Accept'] are not allowed. Nov
>   25, 2015 4:58:55 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
>   SEVERE: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.BadRequestException:
>   The argument(s) [u'Accept'] are not allowed. at
>   com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.execute(WatsonService.java:128)
>   at
>   com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.TextToSpeech.synthesize(TextToSpeech.java:119)

I'd appreciate some help with this please and want to use the java API rather than the REST calls.

Thanks.

Comment: Line 116 of the TextToSpeech class https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/text_to_speech/v1/TextToSpeech.java appears to be where the "Accept" query argument gets added. It seems to add query parameter HttpHeaders.ACCEPT rather than the string "accept" which may be something to do with the cause of the error?

Comment: It seems to be adding "Accept" as a query parameter rather than adding into the HttpHeader is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java-SDK is sending `Accept` instead of `accept`(rocky mistake).

A workaround until our next release is to extend the `TextToSpeech` class and override:

```
InputStream synthesize(final String text, final Voice voice, final String outputFormat)
```

Example:

```
public class TextToSpeechHotFix extends TextToSpeech {

  @Override
  public InputStream synthesize(final String text, final Voice voice, final String outputFormat) {
    final RequestBuilder request = RequestBuilder.get(PATH_SYNTHESIZE);
    request.withQuery(TEXT, text);
    request.withQuery(VOICE, voice.getName());

    if (outputFormat != null && !outputFormat.startsWith("audio/"))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "format needs to be an audio mime type, for example: audio/wav or audio/ogg; codecs=opus");

    request.withQuery(ACCEPT, outputFormat != null ? outputFormat : HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV);

    final Response response = execute(request.build());
    return ResponseUtil.getInputStream(response);
  }
}
```